# Azure DevOps - show only the current sprint (not future) in Taskboard?

Tags: user-interface, configuration, azure-devops, sprint

When viewing the current sprint in 
`https://dev.azure.com/[OrgName]/[ProjectName]/_sprints/taskboard/[TeamName]`
the board also shows stories & tasks in future sprints.
Is there a way to hide the future sprints?

Comment: You should have a Sprint drop down at the top right. You don't see the choice to choose the current sprint?

Comment: Yes, clicking the current sprint, but future sprint items continue to display too.

Comment: @FooBar Have you resolved the issue by below answer? Any update?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have selected the correct sprint as the screenshot below shows:

[image]

If still can see the future items, you need to open the item to see whether the Iteration is set to future sprint:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click on Filter Icon and Select @CurrentIteration

[image]